# Calculate total hours over a sequence of days

Tags: excel

Have animal species that appear over a series of days. Would like to calculate the total hours that an animal could be recorded, and the total hours a particular animal was recorded.
[Example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/On09q.png)

Screenshot after Pivot:

[image]

Comment: You can use Pivot Table for this.

Comment: Just add animals to the Rows and Max of time to values and Min of time to Values. You can subtract those both to get exactly what you want for each animal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this in Screenshot: I have used Custom Formatting so that you can see what's happening.

[image: Here]

Comment: Let me know if you are not able to do any step to get there.

Comment: Thanks @Mikku, I have edited my original question. Will the pivot table work over multiple days. When my edit shows up there is a screen shot of pivot table from data.

Comment: @user11668168 ... I think It should, Otherwise a little tweek would do. Show me how the data is spread over days.

Comment: @user11668168 .... The times are in Continuous Format Right ? that is in one day you don't want to skip any hours like for Night time Right ?

Comment: @user11668168 ... Or if you can .. share your workbook, I will make the pivot and you can then see how it's done for future reference.

Comment: @user11668168 ... You will have to share a link of Google Drive or Dropbox or anything like that.

Comment: @user11668168 ... [Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ewjXISf1XmVNlXehsuhD3r2GHfkB_Tkn) .. Look at Sheet2

Comment: it does, I've been doing it site by site. Just noticed an issue with a cat. It was present for a short period at 2am, then returned later in the day. The pivot returns 8hours, but the actual occupancy is really only about 2hours.